# boost::bind and virtual functions

Tags: c++, boost

I have he following interface:

```
template <class T>
class AbstractTask {
public:
    virtual void BindTaskCompleted(AbstractTask<T> &bindedTask)=0;
    virtual void Join(TaskResult<T>)=0;
};
```

And the following implentation:

```
template <class T>
class SlaveTask: public AbstractTask<T> {
public:
    typedef boost::function<void(TaskResult<T>)> joinFunction;

    void BindTaskCompleted(AbstractTask<T> &bindedTask)
    {
        /////////////WORK OK//////////////////////////////  
        //bindedTask.Join(result);

        /////////////COMPILATION ERROR/////////////////////
        slaveTaskCompletionFunction=boost::bind(&AbstractTask<T>::Join,bindedTask,result);
    }

     void Join(TaskResult<T> r)
    {
        slaveTaskCompletionFunction(r);
    }

private:
    joinFunction slaveTaskCompletionFunction;
    TaskResult<T> result;

};
```

I'm trying to bind the virtual Join Method of a AbstractTask implementation to a boost::function with the same signature. boost::bind throws 77 compilation errors and I fail to see why.

I thought at first that boost::bind couldn't be use with virtual method but this doesn't seem to be the case:
[Virtual function and boost bind strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955289/virtual-function-and-boost-bind-strange-behavior)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Thomas

Comment: What are the compilation errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you've bound all of the arguments, but the `boost::function` and how you're using it typedef indicates it wants 1 argument.

Change it to the following.

`slaveTaskCompletionFunction=boost::bind(&AbstractTask<T>::Join,&bindedTask,_1);`

Edit: Also, you had a slicing problem when you passed in bindedTask by reference.  You either have to pass it in by pointer, or use `boost::ref`; otherwise, `boost::bind` attempts to make a copy of the `AbstractTask<T>`, and will end up only copying the interface.

Comment: Thanks. Compile and run ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind like this:

```
slaveTaskCompletionFunction=boost::bind(&AbstractTask<T>::Join, &bindedTask, _1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either pass bindedTask pas const ref:

```
   BindTaskCompleted(const AbstractTask<T> &bindedTask)
```

or use boost::ref to bind it:

```
   boost::bind(&AbstractTask<T>::Join,boost::ref(bindedTask),result);
```